# notification in second activity not working

Tags: android

i have posted a question about this an the solution was perfect , but when i merge it with my code there is no result , the app dont make the notification ,

like here i put " mo " as the start activity .
here is my code :

```
 public class mo extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mo);

}
```

and the second was which has the alarm manager :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
    notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

   // Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Settings calendar for 01/05/2016 12:33:00 AM
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2); // January has value 0
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 18);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM );
   // cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 15);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
```

The broadcastReceiver :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle(" App Notification")
            .setContentText("New Notification From Demmmmo App..")
            .setTicker("New Message Alert!")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
}
```

The notificationActivity :

```
public class NotificationActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notification_activity);
}
}
```

and also here the manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NotificationActivity" />

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".mo"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mo" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: when does exactly the second activity gets called and have you tried debugging it does it reach your broadcast receiver.

Comment: how can i make the notification working in background ? when i call the activity it work but i want it to still working and notify even if i did not call it . so i think must running in background

Comment: see you need to understand that the AlarmManager will not get called untill you start your activity, to let it run in the background you will have to move that code from the activity to maybe a service http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html you can start your service in your first activity.